# Getting image url error code: Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a null variable

Tags: error, error-templates, error-handling

My site just suddenly broke down on a certain page with the following error code, (see screenshot).

[image]

It is occuring for every image on this page and really confusing me.

Any quick suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason, your site isn't able to find the image. And since your Twig code isn't being *defensive*, it's failing ungracefully.

```
{% set image = block.media.first() %}
```

This first part is fine... I'm assuming that `media` is an Assets relationship field. You're attempting to fetch the `first` asset, and set that to `image`. Here's the kicker... **when no assets are found, `image` will be set to NULL**.

This next part is where your problem is...

```
{{ image.url }}
```

That'll work great assuming an asset was found. But when no assets were found, this will trigger an error. Because `image` would be set to NULL, and NULL doesn't have an attribute of `url`. (This is exactly what the error message is telling you.)

Instead, you should write that line more defensively...

```
{{ image ? image.url }}
```

This technique uses the [ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) to first check "if `image` is truthy" before attempting to output `image.url`. In other words, if `image` contains a valid asset, output the image URL.

That way, if no asset is found, you won't get a big nasty error message.

---

On a separate note... You seem to be expressing some urgency that your site has gone down. But the screenshot you showed is clearly a byproduct of being in [`devMode`](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/dev-mode). For the record, you never want to have `devMode` enabled in a live production environment.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to tell from this snippet, but if `image` is an asset field it's important to remember that these are returned as arrays so you have to access the url more like `block.image.first().url`. However, if the image variable is set elsewhere this probably won't help.

EDIT: [Relevant docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#templating)